# Form value empty after post

Tags: go

I am having trouble reading a value from an HTML form in Go, which should be straight forward.  For some reason, the value 'user' in my Auth_login handler is always empty, even after I fill out the form below and press the 'submit' button.

Handler that is called when the /login url is called by an HTTP post method:

```
func Auth_login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    user := r.PostFormValue("username")
    // Other actions here
}
```

Related form (in Slim format):

```
  form action=/login method=post

    br
    | Name:
    br
    input#username type=text

    br
    | Password:
    br
    input#password type=password

    br
    input type=submit
    a href=/login Cancel
```

Am I doing something wrong when trying to read the html form field?

Comment: Method `ParseForm` returns an error value. Is it `nil`? If not what is it?

Comment: No error is returned, it comes up as <nil>

Comment: I just figured it out!  I was setting the ID value of the textbox, but not the 'name' value.  Once I set that, I was able to parse the form!  No wonder it was returning empty strings!!!

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out the answer by looking at another website's source code.  In case anyone has a similar problem, I fixed it by adding a 'name' value to each of the textboxes that I wanted to parse in Go.  For example, the Slim code above would become this:

```
  form action=/login method=post

    br
    | Name:
    br
    input#username type=text name=username

    br
    | Password:
    br
    input#password type=password name=password

    br
    input type=submit
    a href=/login Cancel
```